# how to populate a static UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, fill, populate

I tried several ways but it seems I'm missing something..

Here is the code I use:

```
- (void)configureView
{
// Update the user interface for the detail item.
  if (self.detailItem) {
    for (int idx=0; idx<16; idx++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:idx];
        [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].detailTextLabel.text = [param objectAtIndex:idx];
    }
    self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
  }
}
```

I call this on viewDidLoad. My tableview has 16 static cells, and I'm using standard "Subtitle" type cell, so no customization needed on that front. **textLabel.text** is filled at design time. Also my tableview is in a tableViewController. I also tried with standard population of tableview but it seems static cells don't agree with that way.

What am I doing wrong?

---

@jrturton I did some changes to see what's going on:

I added these three lines under **for** line to see if there's anything there:

```
        UITableView *tv = self.tableView;
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]];
        NSString *label = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:cell.textLabel.text];
```

First of all tv is assigned correctly, I can see that. But other than that cell and label comes empty. Even tv has no row information it seems..

Could it be because tableview has datasource and delegate assigned to the tableviewcontroller.. I think I heard it shouldn't be like that or something...

---

@jrturton Here it is:

[image: static cells]

[image: tableview]

[image: storyboard]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some logging would quicky show you that your index path is not valid and therefore no cell is being returned.

To create an NSIndexPath for use in a UITableView, use this method:

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0];
```

The index path has to contain a row and section for the table to understand it.

You also need to call this from `viewWillAppear:` rather than viewDidLoad, the static table is not populated that early on. And you **must** call `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` first!

Comment: Hmm, I tried it.. Both on **viewDidAppear** and **viewWillAppear**. But it seems both didn't work either... I modified assignment to this.       `[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]].detailTextLabel.text = [param objectAtIndex:idx];`

Comment: Can you check that your method is actually returning a cell? In the debugger, check that the table view exists, the cell is returned and so forth, and that [param objectAtIndex:] is actually returning something? When you have so many nested methods it becomes very hard to debug

Comment: BTW is there an actual example to this static table views? Only thing I did see was on WWDC 2011 with coffee application and as far as I know its code isn't shared with developers (only in presentation).

Comment: Is your view controller a subclass of UITableViewController (it must be)? And are you implementing any datasource methods (number of rows etc) - you must not.

Comment: Yes it's subclass of UITableViewController and no I'm not implementing any datasource methods. Only code I execute for tableview is here.

Comment: OK, and you've said that the tableview is connected to your view controller as the delegate and datasource. Can you show a screenshot of the storyboard with the static cells in it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10824/discussion-between-plato-and-jrturton)

Comment: Moving the code from **viewDidAppear** to **viewWillAppear** solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using -viewWillAppear: with static cells created via Storyboard and -cellForRowAtIndexPath: always returns nil (and, yes, the table view exists, -numberOfSections returns the proper #, no data source methods in play, -viewWillAppear: on super is being called first, etc.). Hmm ...

Comment: @joedandrea probably best to ask a new question. Link to this one if necessary but explain what you've got so far and why it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Try `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  Calling super doesn't seem to matter.